# Move an element from right to left like panel using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am creating a custom panel that should be coming in from right to left and then stay at whatever width of its body. I want this panel coming inside of its container. In my case its inside the "box" div. I am unable to achieve the same. Can someone help here.

```
.box {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 3px black;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  outline: 0;
}

.panel:target {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```
function App() {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="box">
      {drawerOpen ? (
        <SlideDrawer show={drawerOpen} {...{ setDrawerOpen }} />
      ) : null}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setDrawerOpen(!drawerOpen);
        }}
      >
        Click me!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export default function SlideDrawer({ setDrawerOpen, show }) {
  return <div className="panel">I am sliding</div>;
}
```

Sanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sliding-pane-v2-4xuj57?file=/src/index.js:144-504

Comment: Your question is how to do a two-direction css transition?  Looking at your CodePent, the panel slides out ok, but then snaps in without a transition.

Comment: @Yogi,thats right. John's answer makes it sliding in transition fine. But sliding out transition needs to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Updated so that on button click, it toggles the `panel` open and close.

It turns out `transition` is easier to handle a two-way animation in this use case. I deleted some irrelevant code from original answer.

The only trade-off is to keep `SlideDrawer` rendered out of the box so it can be animated both ways.

Here is [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sliding-2-ways-transition-forked-5i0wuc?file=/src/index.js) of it finished.

Hope this will help!

Example: **(replaces `index.js` file)**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SlideDrawer from "./SlideDrawer.jsx";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [drawerOpen, setDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="box">
      <SlideDrawer show={drawerOpen} />
      <button onClick={() => setDrawerOpen((prev) => !prev)}>Click me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Example: **(replaces `SlideDrawer.jsx` file)**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function SlideDrawer({ show }) {
  return <div className={`panel ${show && "slidein"}`}>I am sliding</div>;
}
```

Example: **(replaces `styles.css` file)**

```
.box {
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 3px black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 180px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 0;
  transform: translateX(120%);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.slidein {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

Comment: @li97 I just noticed as well, and I have updated the example to be hopefully closer to your desired result.

Comment: thanks.  when I am clicking on Click me for the first time, it animates and shows up.How can I move it away with animation, say on click of the button. Right now its just vanishes , I want the animation when moving out too

Comment: @li97 I see, but by doing that you would have to manage another `exiting` state and have the `panel` stays rendered (but of out sight, just outside of box).  Would that be okay?

Comment: I thought the same could be achieved by using CSS just like sliding in transition. Can you show me your react approach?I guess the panel is already conditionally rendered,so when the state is false irs however removed

Comment: @li97 Yes exactly, because if the condition to render `panel` is off, there will be not exit animation because `panel` it does not exist anymore. But later I will update with my approach to this anyway.

Comment: thanks much my man. Please let me know if there is any way we can achieve this with having panel having to be conditionally rendered instead of having it all time.